# SQL query to get max from a column but also keeping another column which is not part pf group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to get max on w_cost on v_id and if w_cost is Null then take r_cost and list result as given in below table. How do I get av_id when group by is on v_id to get max w_cost?

```
s_id sg_id  r_cost  w_cost  av_id v_id
123  100    0.50    1.00    1     333
123  105    0.75    0       2     333
123  330    1.00    Null    3     888
```

The final result should be:

```
s_id v_id   w_cost  av_id
123  333     1.00   1
123  888     1.00   3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand from your description (your example is ambiguous unfortunately), something like this might do it:

```
SELECT S_ID,
       V_ID,
       W_COST,
       AV_ID
       FROM (SELECT S_ID,
                    V_ID,
                    COALESCE(W_COST, R_COST) W_COST,
                    AV_ID,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY V_ID
                                       ORDER BY COALESCE(W_COST, R_COST) DESC) RN
                    FROM ELBAT)
       WHERE RN = 1;
```

It gets one row where `COALESCE(W_COST, R_COST)` is the highest for all `V_ID`. If there are more rows with the maximum, only one of them gets chosen randomly (If you want the ties, replace `ROW_NUMBER()` with `RANK()`). `COALESCE(W_COST, R_COST)` uses `R_COST`, if `W_COST IS NULL`, `W_COST` otherwise. The column named `W_COST` in the output also shows the value for `COALESCE(W_COST, R_COST)` (otherwise, if it would show `W_COST` directly, it would show `NULL` in the row for `V_ID` equal to `888`).

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=047a675d99ecaf2459e6d69ac198c808)

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL supports analytics functions, I would do something like this.

```
SELECT
  s_id,
  v_id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN w_cost IS NULL THEN r_cost ELSE w_cost END) OVER (PARTITION BY v_id) AS w_cost,
  av_id
FROM [YOUR_TABLE]
```

In this query you don't need to group by v_id.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks but it should return only 2 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
SQL> with test (s_id, sg_id, r_cost, w_cost, av_id, v_id) as
  2  (select 123, 100, 0.5, 1, 1, 333 from dual union all
  3   select 123, 105, 0.75, 0, 2, 333 from dual union all
  4   select 123, 330, 1, null, 3, 888 from dual
  5  )
  6  select t.s_id,
  7         t.v_id,
  8         max(nvl(t.w_cost, t.r_cost)) w_cost,
  9         (select t1.av_id
 10          from test t1
 11          where nvl(w_cost, r_cost) = (select max(nvl(t2.w_cost, t2.r_cost))
 12                                       from test t2)
 13            and t1.s_id = t.s_id
 14            and t1.v_id = t.v_id
 15         ) av_id
 16  from test t
 17  group by t.s_id, t.v_id
 18  order by 1, 2;

      S_ID       V_ID     W_COST      AV_ID
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       123        333          1          1
       123        888          1          3

SQL>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you want:

```
select t.*
from t
where (s_id, v_id, coalesce(w_cost, r_cost)) in (
          select s_id, v_id, max(coalesce(w_cost, r_cost))
          from t
          group by s_id, v_id
         );
```